# Discord.js -> How do I use the kick command (has it's own file) in index.js in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I have this kick command I made in another file with module.exports etc.

My problem is, how do I run that file in index.js so when I type the command in Discord, that it actually kicks someone.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: 'Kick a member',
    userPermissions: ["KICK_MEMBERS"],
    options: [
        {
            name: 'target',
            description: 'target to kick',
            type: 'USER',
            required: true
        }, 
        {
            name: 'reason',
            description: 'reason for this kick',
            type: 'STRING',
            required: false
        }
    ],


    run: async(client, interaction, args) => {
        const target = interaction.options.getMember('target');
        const reason = 
            interaction.options.getString('reason') || "No reason provided";

        if(
            target.roles.highest.position >= 
            interaction.member.roles.highest.position
            ) 
            
                return interaction.followUp({ 
                    content: 
                        'You can not take action on this user as their role is heigher than yours',
                });

        await target.send(
            `You have been kicked from ${interaction.guild.name}, reason: ${reason}`
            
            );

        target.kick(reason);

        interaction.followUp({
            content: `Kicked ${target.user.tag} successfully! reason: ${reason}`,
        });
    },
}
```

And this is what I use in order to run it in index.js <-- which doesn't work. It works on ping command etc, but not on ban or kick.

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if(command == 'help'){
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message)
    }

    if(command == 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message)
    }

    if(command == 'kick'){
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message)
    }

    if(command == 'ban'){
        client.commands.get('ban').execute(message)
    }
})
```

Could anyone help me with this? I would appreciate it a lot

Comment: What have you done to debug this so far? Saying something "doesn't work" without providing more context isn't very helpful, unfortunately. Does the command even get recognized in the conditional (`if(command == 'kick')`)? Does the `run` method actually get triggered?

Comment: client.commands.get('ban').execute(message)
                                   ^

TypeError: client.commands.get(...).execute is not a function

this is what I get

Comment: But other commands work as expected? So it's probably something with `client.commands.get('kick')` that is not returning what you'd expect. Add some logging or breakpoints to that part of the code to inspect what the value is compared to what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: `run: async` should be `execute: async`

Answer (score 0):

You have your kick command set up to be used as a slash command (interaction) but it’s listening for the command in `messageCreate` rather than `interactionCreate`.

Assuming your bot is configured to store commands in a map, you need to have it listen for commands under the client.on(‘interactionCreate’) event.

Add this code to that event listener:

```js
       if (interaction.isCommand()) {
            const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (!command) {
                return interaction.reply({
                    content: "An error has occurred ",
                    ephemeral: true
                }).catch((error) => client.utils.log.handler("error", error));
            }
            const args = {};
            for (const option of interaction.options.data) {
                if (option.type === "SUB_COMMAND") {
                    if (option.name) args[option.name] = true;
                    option.options?.forEach((x) => {
                        args[x.name] = x.value;
                    });
                } else if (option.value) {
                    args[option.name] = option.value;
                }
            }
            interaction.member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id);
            try {
                command.run(client, interaction, args);
            } catch (error) {
                client.utils.log.error(error);
                interaction.reply({
                    content: "There was an error while executing this command!",
                    ephemeral: true
                }).catch((err) => client.utils.log.handler("error", err));
            }
        }
```

If you don’t have your commands mapped, map them with this code outside of a listener event - add above your `client.login(token)`

Change ./commands to whatever location you have your commands stored.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

client.commands = new Collection()
const commandList = []
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
    commandList.push(` ${file.split('.')[0]}`)
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command)
}
console.log(`${commandFiles.length} commands loaded. ${commandList}`)
```

Comment: Updated answer since command is expecting args to be defined already.